# how to determine the opened outlook appointment item by user is an occurrence, exception or master series in compose mode through Office.js?

Tags: office365api, office-js, office365-apps, outlook-web-addins

In the context of calendar recurrence event(appointment) in compose mode through Office.js I need to set custom properties to the respective appointment  master series item either the opened event by user is an occurrence, exception or master series.

Here's the problem I am facing through office.js API is, I'm not able to identify the opened appointment by user is an occurrence, exception or master series. How can I identify it? If it's an occurrence or exception then how can I add custom property to the respective master series item from current item context through the Office.js.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated the API unfortunately does not provide this information. However you can use the `item->seriesId` property to at least distinguish the Series master from the instances. If the id is present you're dealing with an instance, else a master.

Please note that there seems to be a Bug in the Mac Version that makes the `seriesId` unavailable there. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324199/seriesid-missing-in-outlook-2019-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

There is no javascript api in Office.js to determine whether an appointment is master, recurring, or an exception. **In order to do this however, you can use a [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#get-events):**

`GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{event_id}`

The [response](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#EventResource) will include an EventType (SeriesMaster,Occurence,Exception) and the series master id (null if it is a master)

**Alternatively** you can use the [makeEwsRequestAsync() API](https://dev.outlook.com/reference/add-ins/Office.context.mailbox.html#makeEwsRequestAsync) and send a [GetItem EWS request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643672(v=exchg.150).aspx#Anchor_2).

The response you will receive from the request will have several properties that will help you with this:

- IsRecurring
- IsException
- RecurringMasterItemId

You can then use the Recurring Master ItemId to add a custom property using an additional [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#update-events) call or EWS Call