# SeriesId missing in Outlook 2019 on Mac

Tags: office-js, outlook-for-mac

In order to determine whether an `AppointmentCompose` item that has a Recurrence object attached is actually the Series or an Instance we check the `seriesId` on the item. According to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_7/office.item?view=office-js#seriesid) this should return `null` for the series item and the parent id for any Instance of a Series.

This works well for Outlook on Windows and in the Web (as long as the RequirementsSet 1.7 is supported). However on Outlook for Mac this also returns a falsy result for instances. We consider this a bug in the Mac implementation. Can you please check and provide an ETA for a fix?

Looking at the objects we also realize that an the internal state seems to miss several properties on the `AppointmentCompose->_data->_data` object and has a wrong value of `false` on the `AppointmentCompose->_recurrence$p$2->_isInstance$p$0`.

Comment: Just in case this bug is still relevant:

"However on Outlook for Mac this also returns a falsy result for instances." 
What do you mean by 'falsy' result? Can you share the result with us and perhaps provide a comparison between the results you got on different platforms (win/owa/mac)?

Under what conditions are you getting AppointmentCompose->_recurrence$p$2->_isInstance$p$0 as false?

Comment: @Mac_Outlook_Extensibility Sorry I didn't see this earlier. With 'falsy' I refer to [Javascript boolean evalutaion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). As explained on Win and Web we get the seriesId (a string) for instances of an appointment series. On mac the value evaluates in !seriesId to true.